# Error in st_transform.sfc(st_geometry(x), crs, ...) : cannot transform sfc object with missing crs

Tags: r, r-sf

```
dput(head(uber_data))
structure(list(Date.Time = structure(c(1396311060, 1396311420, 
1396311660, 1396312080, 1396312380, 1396312380), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Lat = c(40.769, 40.7267, 40.7316, 
40.7588, 40.7594, 40.7383), Lon = c(-73.9549, -74.0345, -73.9873, 
-73.9776, -73.9722, -74.0403), Base = c("B02512", "B02512", "B02512", 
"B02512", "B02512", "B02512"), Time = c("00:11:00", "00:17:00", 
"00:21:00", "00:28:00", "00:33:00", "00:33:00"), Day = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"29", "30", "31"), class = "factor"), Month = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", 
"Sep"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Year = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "2014", class = "factor"), Hour = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"), class = "factor"), 
    Minute = structure(c(12L, 18L, 22L, 29L, 34L, 34L), levels = c("0", 
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
    "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
    "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", 
    "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"), class = "factor"), 
    Second = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "0", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")



 uber_trip_data <-
      uber_data %>% 
      select(-`Date.Time`, -Base) %>% 
      st_as_sf(coords = c("Lon", "Lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
      st_transform(crs = 102003) %>% 
      st_coordinates() %>% 
      as.data.frame()
```

This is the error i get :

"Error in CPL_transform(x, crs, aoi, pipeline, reverse, desired_accuracy,  :    crs not found: is it missing? In addition: Warning message: In CPL_crs_from_input(x) :   GDAL Error 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: crs not found"

I tried looking everywhere for this but none of them actually helped. It just gives me a new error each time. I tried using crs = "ERSI:4326" but that doesn't work as well. I dont know what seems to be the problem.

Comment: without some data (`dput(head(uber_data))`) it is difficult to help you since we can not run our own tests. best guess is that your `st_as_sf()`-command somehow fails to add the `wgs_84 pseudo mercator` crs to your coordinates...

Comment: I have added in the data (dput(head(uber_data)))

Comment: ok i got your problem. the code works fine but sf does not know crs `102003`. i have tried with different crs and it worked just fine

Comment: ah okay, what did you change it to?

Comment: I believe that you need to change the transformation to Albers to read `st_transform(crs = "ESRI:102003")`

Comment: I transformed it from 4326 to 3857 with no issue. tried some others as well (planar ones just to makes ure) all without issue

Comment: Alternatively you can use 5070 for alternative take on Albers; have a look at https://epsg.io/102003 &  https://epsg.io/5070

Comment: I got the fix, Thank you so much Jindra and D.J for your help. Was cracking my head on this one for the past hour. Both your solution works!

Comment: glad to hear that! just keep in mind that the output of EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) and EPSG:5070 (Albers USA) is rather different. On the other hand EPSG:5070 and ESRI:102003 should be roughly on the same page.

Comment: @JindraLacko You are exactly right! It might be worth a try to check which Albers CRS is closest to the location analyzed (California Albers: 3310, or Quebec Albers: 6624, etc...)